# Vulkan: update uniform buffer each frame

Tags: c++, synchronization, buffer, vulkan

I want to update uniform buffer each frame, but I don't want to create separate buffers per frame.
I want to have one buffer per material for simplicity.

What is the best method for update this buffer?

I've tried to use mapped buffer, but I have some rendering artifacts, when buffer is updating.

Now I'm trying to use vkCmdCopyBuffer with vkCmdPipelineBarrier and I use temprorary CommandBuffer (s_cmd) because frame's CommandBuffer is within a render pass instance.

Everything looks fine, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

```
auto s_cmd = getVulkanRenderer()->beginSingleTimeCommands();

VulkanBuffer stagingBuffer(
    vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eTransferSrc,
    sizeof(glm::mat4[2]),
    VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_AUTO_PREFER_HOST,
    VMA_ALLOCATION_CREATE_MAPPED_BIT | VMA_ALLOCATION_CREATE_HOST_ACCESS_SEQUENTIAL_WRITE_BIT
);
stagingBuffer.updateRange(data, sizeof(data), 0);

auto buffer_barrier_1 = vk::BufferMemoryBarrier{}
    .setBuffer(material_instance->uniformBuffer->getNativeHandle())
    .setOffset(0)
    .setSize(sizeof(glm::mat4[2]))
    .setSrcAccessMask(vk::AccessFlagBits::eHostWrite)
    .setDstAccessMask(vk::AccessFlagBits::eTransferRead)
    .setSrcQueueFamilyIndex(VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED)
    .setDstQueueFamilyIndex(VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED);
s_cmd.pipelineBarrier(
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eHost,
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eTransfer,
    vk::DependencyFlags{},
    {},
    {buffer_barrier_1},
    {}
);
s_cmd.copyBuffer(stagingBuffer.getNativeHandle(), material_instance->uniformBuffer->getNativeHandle(), {
    vk::BufferCopy(0, 0, sizeof(glm::mat4[2]))
});
auto buffer_barrier_2 = vk::BufferMemoryBarrier{}
    .setBuffer(material_instance->uniformBuffer->getNativeHandle())
    .setOffset(0)
    .setSize(sizeof(glm::mat4[2]))
    .setSrcAccessMask(vk::AccessFlagBits::eTransferRead)
    .setDstAccessMask(vk::AccessFlagBits::eVertexAttributeRead)
    .setSrcQueueFamilyIndex(VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED)
    .setDstQueueFamilyIndex(VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED);

s_cmd.pipelineBarrier(
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eTransfer,
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eVertexInput,
    vk::DependencyFlags{},
    {},
    {buffer_barrier_2},
    {}
);
getVulkanRenderer()->endSingleTimeCommands(s_cmd);
```

Comment: Are you really doing a whole memory transfer for just 128 bytes of memory at a time? Also, are you copying to memory that is already being used by prior graphics operations?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, this buffer is used by prior graphics operations, so I insert pipeline barriers. If you know better implementation, I'll appreciate it

Comment: Mapping memory when you have CPU Access, aka the uniform buffer is in system memory is perfectly fine. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. What is data? Unless it is stack memory, I can see it is wrong. Why don't you use `sizeof(data)` instead of `sizeof(glm::mat4[2])` ?

Comment: @vikAy data is just a glm::mat4 data[2] so sizeof(data) is same as sizeof(glm::mat4[2]). I can't just map uniform buffer and write data to it directly, because this buffer is used in prior frame